# How do i change the color of some words in sentence without it going to next line in html

Tags: html

I need to change the color of certain words in a sentence. What are the best ways to do it? I tried several things but cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: What are the "several things" you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use spans to target certain sections with a class or id.

```html
<!-- markup -->
<p> Hello. Some <span class="blue">words</span> are <span class="blue">colored</span> and some are <span class="blue">not</span>. </p>
```

```css
/* styles */
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`span` is an `inline` element by default. You can "inject" it into your sentence and style properly:

**HTML**

```
<p>
  Lorem <span class="span1">ipsum</span> dolor <span class="span2">sit<span> amet.
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.span1 {
  color: #f00;
}
.span2 {
  color: #0f0;
}
```